# Android Wear: how to dismiss notification faster than standard 5 seconds delay?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am sending notifications to Android Wear.

They are displayed correctly and can be dismissed by swiping to the right side of the watch, but it takes about 5 seconds delay before they are dismissed on the phone.

I think that delay is standard for Android Wear, so the dismissal can be canceled by the user.

But my client wants immediate reaction on dismissal.

Is there any way to get rid of that delay or at least decrease it?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: This was a small side project 5 years ago. In the end my client didn't care about this behavior any longer. So I stopped searching.